# Set of Rc<T> where T isn't Hash or Ord?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to have a set of `Rc<T>`s in Rust (similar to `HashSet<Rc<T>>`) without `T` being `Hash` or `Ord`?

```rust
struct Foo { /* Lots of members, expensive to Hash or Ord */ }
```

I want to have a set of `Rc<Foo>` references in a set in order to avoid duplicates. I understand that `HashSet<Rc<T>>` is expecting `T: Hash` and `BTreeSet<Rc<T>>` expects `T: Ord`:

```rust
let mut hash_set = HashSet::<Foo>::new();
hash_set.insert(Foo {}); // error[E0599]: trait bounds were not satisfied

let mut tree_set = BTreeSet::<Foo>::new(); // error[E0277]: trait bound `Foo: Ord` is not satisfied
tree_set.insert(Foo {});
```

But I don't want to compare by values of `Foo` objects, I want the set to compare by `Rc` references. My understanding is that if I change the value of the underlying `Foo` object, the `Rc` still points to the same heap address. Therefore that heap address could be used as the basis of hashing or ordering, which is exactly what I want.

Is that possible with Rust's std? Or maybe some crate? Or is my understanding of `Rc`'s incorrect?

Comment: Note that `Rc` doesn't guarantee that the heap address of the value won't change. You need `Pin<Rc<T>>` for that (can be created with [`Rc::pin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.pin/)). Then maybe you can use [`Rc::as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.as_ptr) to get a raw pointer (that is `Hash` and `Ord`).

Comment: @Jmb I don't think this is true. `Rc` never reallocates, so the pointer will remain stable. Pinning only prevents moving the value out of the `Rc`, e.g. by means of `std::mem::replace()`, which we don't care about here – it doesn't change the pointer the `Rc` is pointing to. Moreover, the vast majority of types are `Unpin`, so pinning doesn't do anything for them.

Comment: @Jmb The allocation can't change if there are other `Rc`s pointing to the same allocation. Since the set will hold some `Rc`s, that is guaranteed and no explicit pinning should be needed.

Comment: @SvenMarnach the pointer will remain stable _in the current implementation,_ but this is not guaranteed by `Rc`'s contract.

Comment: @Jmb There may not be an explicit guarantee, but in general it's just not _possible_ for the pointer value to change, since there may be other `Rc`s pointing to the same data. And in any case, pinning won't help, since amlost all types are `Unpin`. This is not what pinning is for.

Comment: I realized that it's actually possible to make an `Rc` reallocate with `Rc::make_mut()`, which will disassociate it from other pointers to the same allocation. I don't think this is a problem, though, since the new allocation actually _should_ be considered separate from the original one in that case.

Comment: Reading [this page](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/04_pinning/01_chapter.html), I'd say that this is exactly what pinning is for, but that for it to work you need to ensure that `Foo` is `!Unpin`, e.g. by adding a `_marker: std::marker::PhantomPinned` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a wrapper for your `Rc` type. A starting idea would be to use addresses as you suggested. You will need to implement `Hash`, `Eq`, and `PartialEq`.

```rust
use std::hash::Hash;

struct Foo {}

struct RcHashFoo(Rc<Foo>);

impl PartialEq for RcHashFoo {
    fn eq(&self, other: &RcHashFoo) -> bool {
        Rc::ptr_eq(&self.0, &other.0)
    }
}

impl Eq for RcHashFoo {}

impl Hash for RcHashFoo {
    fn hash<H>(&self, hasher: &mut H) where H: Hasher { 
        hasher.write_usize(Rc::as_ptr(&self.0) as usize);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ce96595f1e26d62083828d322d007572)

Comment: As pointed out by Sven Marnach, there is no need for a `Pin` version of the code, it only complicates the answer without providing a useful value. Pinning serves to prevent moving a non-`Unpin` `T` _out_ of a smart pointer by way of `std::mem::replace()` or equivalent. Since your `Hash` and `PartialEq` only use the pointer itself and don't depend on the contents of `T`, they don't require the `Rc` to be pinned.

Comment: @user4815162342, thanks for the explanation. I was confused since the beginning. I really didnt knew the contracts Rc does with the memory system. Thanks for comments and the explanations. The TIL highlight :)

Comment: Also, you can use `Rc::ptr_eq` to compare two pointers. In `hash()` you probably want to use `hasher.write_usize()`, and cast the pointer to `usize`. `usize` is guaranteed to accommodate a pointer, and using it will be a tad more efficient on 32-bit platforms.

Comment: @user4815162342, absolutely right. I will update :)